# Bulk Edit on Angular Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

The way which I have handled the **row level edition** for `payment received` property as shown below:

```
   <tr ng-repeat="item in Event.ParticipantPledges">
    <div>
        <span ng-if="item.Id != Event.ParticipantPledge.Id">{{item.PaymentReceived | currency}}</span>
        <input type="number" ng-if="item.Id == Event.ParticipantPledge.Id" name="paymentReceived" ng-model="Event.ParticipantPledge.PaymentReceived" required />
    </div>
   </tr>
```

I have a grid as shown above.I know how to edit row level as shown above.But my question is how can I do it for all rows at once.In other words bulk edit.I can give a button as `Edit All` and then user can edit any row and after that he can update the records.But when I give a such feature where if user changes one item's value then it apply to all the rows of that item.I know this is happening due to 2 way data binding nature.But could you tell me how to avoid this ? Thanks in advance.

**Note :** Simple example is more than enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used awesome [**Angular-xeditable**](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-table) directive for that.

[image]

***Play with it : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/78/)***

***HTML :***

```
<form editable-form name="tableform" onaftersave="saveTable()" oncancel="cancel()">

    <!-- table -->
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
      <tr style="font-weight: bold">
        <td style="width:40%">Name</td>
        <td style="width:30%">Status</td>
        <td style="width:30%">Group</td>
        <td style="width:30%"><span ng-show="tableform.$visible">Action</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:filterUser">
        <td>
          <!-- editable username (text with validation) -->
          <span editable-text="user.name" e-form="tableform" onbeforesave="checkName($data, user.id)">
            {{ user.name || 'empty' }}
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <!-- editable status (select-local) -->
          <span editable-select="user.status" e-form="tableform" e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in statuses">
            {{ showStatus(user) }}
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <!-- editable group (select-remote) -->
          <span editable-select="user.group" e-form="tableform" onshow="loadGroups()" e-ng-options="g.id as g.text for g in groups">
            {{ showGroup(user) }}
          </span>
        </td>
        <td><button type="button" ng-show="tableform.$visible" ng-click="deleteUser(user.id)" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Del</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- buttons -->
    <div class="btn-edit">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-show="!tableform.$visible" ng-click="tableform.$show()">
        edit
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-form" ng-show="tableform.$visible">
      <button type="button" ng-disabled="tableform.$waiting" ng-click="addUser()" class="btn btn-default pull-right">add row</button>
      <button type="submit" ng-disabled="tableform.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>
      <button type="button" ng-disabled="tableform.$waiting" ng-click="tableform.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default">cancel</button>
    </div> 

  </form>
</div>
```

***JS :***

```
app.controller('EditableTableCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $http, $q) {
  $scope.users = [
    {id: 1, name: 'awesome user1', status: 2, group: 4, groupName: 'admin'},
    {id: 2, name: 'awesome user2', status: undefined, group: 3, groupName: 'vip'},
    {id: 3, name: 'awesome user3', status: 2, group: null}
  ]; 

  $scope.statuses = [
    {value: 1, text: 'status1'},
    {value: 2, text: 'status2'},
    {value: 3, text: 'status3'},
    {value: 4, text: 'status4'}
  ]; 

  $scope.groups = [];
  $scope.loadGroups = function() {
    return $scope.groups.length ? null : $http.get('/groups').success(function(data) {
      $scope.groups = data;
    });
  };

  $scope.showGroup = function(user) {
    if(user.group && $scope.groups.length) {
      var selected = $filter('filter')($scope.groups, {id: user.group});
      return selected.length ? selected[0].text : 'Not set';
    } else {
      return user.groupName || 'Not set';
    }
  };

  $scope.showStatus = function(user) {
    var selected = [];
    if(user.status) {
      selected = $filter('filter')($scope.statuses, {value: user.status});
    }
    return selected.length ? selected[0].text : 'Not set';
  };

  $scope.checkName = function(data, id) {
    if (id === 2 && data !== 'awesome') {
      return "Username 2 should be `awesome`";
    }
  };

  // filter users to show
  $scope.filterUser = function(user) {
    return user.isDeleted !== true;
  };

  // mark user as deleted
  $scope.deleteUser = function(id) {
    var filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.users, {id: id});
    if (filtered.length) {
      filtered[0].isDeleted = true;
    }
  };

  // add user
  $scope.addUser = function() {
    $scope.users.push({
      id: $scope.users.length+1,
      name: '',
      status: null,
      group: null,
      isNew: true
    });
  };

  // cancel all changes
  $scope.cancel = function() {
    for (var i = $scope.users.length; i--;) {
      var user = $scope.users[i];    
      // undelete
      if (user.isDeleted) {
        delete user.isDeleted;
      }
      // remove new 
      if (user.isNew) {
        $scope.users.splice(i, 1);
      }      
    };
  };

  // save edits
  $scope.saveTable = function() {
    var results = [];
    for (var i = $scope.users.length; i--;) {
      var user = $scope.users[i];
      // actually delete user
      if (user.isDeleted) {
        $scope.users.splice(i, 1);
      }
      // mark as not new 
      if (user.isNew) {
        user.isNew = false;
      }

      // send on server
      results.push($http.post('/saveUser', user));      
    }

    return $q.all(results);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As understood by me i think you want to give value first time to all and then give individual values to each row if you want.

For this take Edit all Button and open a popup onclick event on that button.
in popup accept the input and update the angular object by using foreach method. so it will apply to all objects.

I think this will help you...

Upadated this may help you...

```
<div ng-repeat="Event.ParticipantPledge in Event.dataArray track by $index">
    <div>
    <span ng-if="item.Id != Event.ParticipantPledge.Id">{{item.PaymentReceived | currency}}</span>
    <input type="number" ng-if="item.Id == Event.ParticipantPledge.Id" name="paymentReceived" ng-bind="Event.ParticipantPledge.PaymentReceived" required />
    <button onclick="updateValue($index,updatedValue)">Update</button>
</div>
</div>



updateValue(id,value){
    $scope.Event.dataArray[id].ParticipantPledge.PaymentReceived = value;
}
```

Comment: Nope.This is not what I want.I just need to edit all rows manually by using different values.After that user can update the db.

Comment: The problem which I have is when I try to update the single item then that value apply to all the places of the above grid (i.e. same property)

Comment: problem is using same model name for all rows try to use different model name. don't use ng-model use ng-bind and to update the object use object index number and update it manually. like on lcikcing update button call a method which accepts input and updates the respected index value.

Comment: Can I have a simple example ?

Comment: If you show it to a fiction one then more than enough or please show how  to do that on the above property.Above code snippet iterates inside the `ng-repeat` directive.

Comment: i need to know which object you are using so i can use use tarck by index in ng-repeat and pass that value and need original object which holding the grid data so please at least share ng-repeat code then i may help you

Comment: According to your code snippet where update button is inside the grid.But I need to do a bulk update.Update button must away from the grid.

Answer (score 0):

The issue wrt all rows having same value on edit is you are bind input of all rows to the same model "ng-model="Event.ParticipantPledge.PaymentReceived". Instead you should bind to that rows model i.e bind the input to say, item.paymentReceived. Then when you have update all button outside you can loop through all the items and get the value and update db.

http://jsfiddle.net/twx2p7s9/1/

```
<div ng-repeat="line in lines">
  <input ng-model="line.text"/>
</div>
```