# table batch edit in MEAN stack (Angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

i am using html table to bind the data with the help of angular(ng-repeat).now i need crud operation its working crctly in row wise .my need is i want a batch edit in angularjs

Thanks[image]

Comment: Have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199050/bulk-edit-on-angular-grid, maybe is what you are looking for

Comment: hi @leze that link is fine but there each row have a save button .when i click edit means whole row change to editable but my need is user click a particular cell that cell should be change into editable not column edit or row edit

Comment: Try to add `gridOptions: { enableCellEdit: true,enableCellEditOnFocus: true }` to your grid config, and on your cell div `<div ui-grid="vm.gridOptions" ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit ...>`